# How to disprove Russell's paradox in ZF?

Tags: set-theory, paradoxes

How to avoid a Russell-style paradox in ZF?

The Zermelo-Fraenkel system, by not using a theory of types, does not prevent us from posing Russell's paradoxical scheme. Only when the argument is replaced by the set being defined, the resulting statement is false, not paradoxical.

Set R in Frege's system:

By the axiom of unrestricted comprehension:

∃y ∀x ( x ∈ y ) ⟺ F(x)

... where F (x) is any well-formed formula of the system. Replacing the formula, and the existential by the name of the defined set:

∀x ( x ∈ R ) ⟺ ( x ∉ x )

Instantiating the variable x with R:

( R ∈ R ) ⟺ ( R ∉ R )

Set R in the ZF system:

By the axiom of specification (also called separation):

∀z ∃y ∀x [ ( x ∈ y ) ⇔  ( x ∈ z  ) ∧ F(x) ]

Replacing the schema of the formula with a concrete formula, and the existential one with the name of the defined set:

|1|:    ∀z ∀x [ ( x ∈ R ) ⟺  ( x ∈ z  ) ∧  ( x ∉ x ) ]

We cannot replace x by R, because there is no set z of which it is a member, therefore the second member of the equivalence does not hold.

The ZF system also allows defining the R’s complement independently, that is, without using the set R in its definition, but simply as the set M of all self-belonging sets, those that are members of themselves.

```
∀z ∀x [ ( x ∈ M ) ⟺  ( x ∈ z  ) ∧  ( x ∈ x ) ]
```

Then you can build the complement of M, which is the complement of the complement of R, without in principle its double complement condition being evident:

```
∀z ∀x [ ( x ∈ MC ) ⟺  ( x ∈ z  ) ∧  ( x ∉ M ) ]
```

Then instantiating in the formula |1|:

∀z [ ( MC ∈ R ) ⟺  ( MC ∈ z  ) ∧  ( MC ∉ MC ) ]

But MC is the complement of the complement of R, so that it can be shown that:

```
( MC ⊆  R ∧ R ⊆ MC ) ⟹ ( R ≡ MC )
```

That is, MC and R are two names for the same set; thus:

```
∀z [ ( R ∈ R ) ⟺ ( R ∈ z  ) ∧  ( R ∉ R ) ]
```

If we assume that R ∈ R, then:

( R ∈ R )  ⟹  ∀z ( R ∈ z  ) ∧  ( R ∉ R )
∀z ( R ∈ z  ) ∧  ( R ∉ R )                            [ by Modus Ponens ]
( R ∉ R )                                                           [ conjunction elimination ]

If we assume that R ∉ R, then:

```
∀z ( R ∈ z  ) ∧  ( R ∉ R )  ⟹  ( R ∈ R )
```

If we suppose that R is a member of all sets it is easily followed that it is a member of itself, by Modus Ponens.

If we assume that R is not a member of some set, R would not be defined, contrary to what we had assumed in the formula |1|.

For all of which:

( R ∈ R  ) ⟺  ( R ∉ R )

I assume there will be a way to disprove this reasoning, but at the moment I can't get a glimpse of it.

[[image: Explanation of W.v.O. Quine, about the axiom scheme][1]]

Comment: I don’t think you’ve quoted the Axiom Schema of Separation correctly. I believe the correct statement is $\forall z\exists y\forall x((x\in y)\iff (x\in z\wedge \Phi(x)))$.  You have the $\exists y$ first, which would make $y$ independent of $z$; and you have $z$ quantified existentially instead of universally.

Comment: Essentially, Separation says that for every set $z$, there is a set $y$ which contains precisely the $x$ that are elements of (the fixed) $z$ for which $\Phi$ is true; your statement instead says that there is a set $y$ which contains every $x$ that has the property of satisfying $\Phi$ *and* belonging to some set $z$ (which may depends on $x$). That’s a very different statement. The latter statement would, for example, imply (together with the Axiom of the Power set) the existence of a set of all sets, whereas the usual Axiom of Separation does not imply any such thing.

Comment: Re: your addition, see my edit. It's got the right form of the axiom; you're misreading/misinterpreting it.

Comment: Now I use the version of the Zermelo axiomatic separation scheme that you prefer.
The paradox keeps appearing.

Comment: @AbelPeralta See my edit. It's still wrong, this time since you've tried to perform an illegal existential instantiation.

Comment: It’s not a matter of “preference.” What you had was **wrong**, plain and simple. This statement is **correct.** I guess you might say I “prefer” correct statements to incorrect ones, but one would think that this is a matter of “doing mathematics”, not of “preference”. Your use of “preference” is either disingenuous, or a reflection of some really serious misunderstanding and misconceptions on your part.

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice example of the subtlety of existential instantiation (replacing an existentially-quantified variable with a constant symbol). Specifically:

### You cannot instantiate while bound by a universal quantifier.

To see what I mean, consider the following. The sentence $$\forall u\exists v(u<v)$$ is obviously true in $\mathbb{N}$. However, if we try to instantiate $v$, we get $$\forall u(u<C)$$ (here "$C$" is our new constant symbol) which is clearly false in $\mathbb{N}$ no matter how we interpret $C$.

---

In your argument, this is exactly what you do e.g. when you write

> Replacing [...] the existential one with the name of the defined set:

the sentence "$\forall z\color{red}{\exists y}\forall x[x\in \color{red}{y}\leftrightarrow (x\in z\wedge x\not\in x)]$" is provable from separation but the sentence "$\forall z\forall x[x\in \color{red}{R}\leftrightarrow (x\in z\wedge x\not\in x)]$" is completely unjustified, and indeed $\mathsf{ZF}$ *disproves* the existence of an $R$ having that property.

---

There *is* a way to correctly instantiate inside a universal quantifier: introduce a *function* symbol taking as input the variables corresponding to universal quantifiers outside the relevant existential quantifier. Thinking of constant symbols as $0$-ary function symbols, this generalizes the version of existential instantiation we're used to in the case where there are no "outside universals."

This transformation is actually extremely useful - it's [**Skolemization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form#How_Skolemization_works). But that doesn't lead to a contradiction here: we just wind up building the function $z\mapsto \{x\in z: x\not\in x\}$, which is in fact $z\mapsto z$ by regularity.

Comment: Now I use the version of the Zermelo axiomatic separation scheme that you prefer.
The paradox keeps appearing.

Comment: @AbelPeralta No, your argument is still wrong: the sets $R$, $M$, and so on **depend on $z$**. As soon as you start ignoring the "$\exists y$"s and specifically the fact that *they sit within the scope of the "$\forall z$s"*, you're making a mistake. You can't existentially instantiate inside a universal quantifier (the "$\forall z$"). (And re: the axiom of separation, it's not "the version I prefer," it's **the axiom as correctly stated** - what you wrote originally was simply incorrect.)